# Reversing a linked list in C, code troubles

Tags: c, macos

I attempted to reverse a simple linked list (containing 0, 1, 2, 3...9) in c, but my code won't fully function. Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure I had the reverse function right, the main thing i'm having trouble with is figuring out what to place into the argument of the reverse() function. This program is very close to functioning, it compiles but it doesn't print the reversed list so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any help that someone can give would be greatly appreciated! :)

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node;
typedef struct node Node;

struct node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void reverse(Node* *);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node* head = NULL;
    int i;
    Node* temp;

    //set up a test list with values 9->8->7->...->0
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            printf("out of memory?\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        temp->data = i;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    reverse(head);

    //print the reversed list.
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void reverse(Node* *head)
{
    Node* pre = NULL;
    Node* cur = NULL;
    Node* nex = NULL;

    pre = cur = nex = *head;
    pre = pre->next->next;
    cur = cur->next;
    nex->next = NULL;
    cur->next = nex;

    while(pre != NULL)
    {
        nex = cur;
        cur = pre;
        pre = pre->next;
        cur->next = nex;
    }

    *head = pre;

}
```

Comment: `reverse` expects a prt-to-ptr. You need to call with `reverse(&head)`.

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about passing `struct Node *` to `reverse` when it is expecting `struct Node **`

Comment: Add some `printf` for debug. For instance, before your `while (temp != NULL)` add `if (temp == NULL) printf("temp is NULL! WHY?! :(\n);`

Comment: Write the list printing code as a function.  Then you can call it more often, which can help you spot problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your `reverse()` function is not correct. It always assigns `*head` to `NULL`. Always.

```
while(pre != NULL)
{
    nex = cur;
    cur = pre;
    pre = pre->next;
    cur->next = nex;
}
```

The only way for this loop to terminate is if `pre` is `NULL`. Then you use that to assign to `*head`:

```
*head = pre;
```

So your result will always be an empty list. Try setting it to `cur` instead.

Also, your function will not work on empty or single-entry lists. And as the comments point out, you need to pass the address of your head pointer -- `reverse(&head)`.

Comment: Oh awesome thank you so much that was the issue! Sorry for my beginner-level knowledge I had gotten an error about that but I wasn't sure how to troubleshoot from there.